# Download CSV directly from the website with Python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm using the code below to try to download csv, but it's not working, can anyone help me with this?

```
import urllib.request, urllib.error, urllib.parse

url = 'https://covid19.who.int/table'
csvfile = r"C:/Users/RONEYGALAN/Desktop/OMS/Covid.csv"

#open main page
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
webContent = response.read()
wc = str(webContent)

#get csv URL
i = wc.find(r"table-data.csv")
i2 = wc.find("/WHO-COVID-19-global-", i-200)
csvURL = "https://covid19.who.int/table" + wc[i2:i+17]
print(csvURL)

#get csv
csvresp = urllib.request.urlopen(csvURL)
csvdata = str(csvresp.read())
print(len(csvdata), "bytes")

#save csv to file
print("Saving To", csvfile)
f = open(csvfile,"w")
f.write(csvdata.replace(r"\r\n","\n"))
f.close()
```

If anyone has any other code suggestions feel free to post

Here's the error that's occurring, I don't know if I'm passing the right parameters to the functions, but as it's the first time I've been working with web scraping, maybe I need some collaboration.

InvalidURL: URL cannot contain control characters. '/table/WHO-COVID-19-global-table-data.csv "d' (found at least '')

Comment: Can you elaborate on what’s unclear to you about the error you provided here?

Comment: It doesn’t seem like the result of `i`, `i2` and consequentially `csvURL` are evaluating to what you expect - can you share the result of `print(csvURL)` and ensure that result meets your expectations? Per my earlier comment, can you also elaborate on what specifically about the error message you don’t understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code at the step of #get csv URL results a wrong url, i.e. `https://covid19.who.int/table/WHO-COVID-19-global-table-data.csv" d`. That's the reason it generated InvalidURL error

Thus, you should remove some redundant characters at the end by changing
`csvURL = "https://covid19.who.int/table" + wc[i2:i+17]`
to
`csvURL = "https://covid19.who.int/table" + wc[i2:i+14]`

Then, it should result in a correct format url `https://covid19.who.int/table/WHO-COVID-19-global-table-data.csv`

Comment: Thank you, now it's saving the file, but it's not coming with the information in the same way as when I download it manually, could it be some parameter I missed?

Comment: The url seems wrong (in location), change ```csvURL = "https://covid19.who.int/table" + wc[i2:i+14]``` to ```csvURL = "https://covid19.who.int" + wc[i2:i+14]```

Comment: I made the change, but it is still not bringing the csv with the correct information.

Comment: I can download the file on my machine. Please describe more particular details on the problem, then we can go from there